# How to remove reflection of car dashboard objects from video Opencv/ Python

Tags: python, opencv, video

currently I'm doing video processing to extract set of lines in the road using opencv ad python. I extracted white lines using color filter.the video I used to process have a reflection of dashboard object and it also included in my filtered image. Since that, some of my averaging going wrong. I want to remove that from my video. I have tried using background subtraction method but it's not removing that object. Is there a way to do it with opencv and python ?.Below the snapshot of video.

[image: reflection of items]
This is what I have done.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
import itertools
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video3.mov')

fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

while (cap.isOpened()):

  ret, frame = cap.read()

  hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)


  # HSL color mask
  lower_white = np.uint8([0, 140, 0])
  upper_white = np.uint8([255, 255, 255])
  mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, upper_white)
  res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
  cv2.imshow("HSL",res)


  rows, cols = hsv.shape[:2]

  bottom_left = [cols * 0, rows * 0.9]
  top_left = [cols * 0.4, rows * 0.7]
  bottom_right = [cols * 1, rows * 0.9]
  top_right = [cols * 0.6, rows * 0.7]

  vertices = np.array([[bottom_left, top_left, top_right, bottom_right]], dtype=np.int32)

  maskzero = np.zeros_like(res)
  cv2.fillPoly(maskzero, vertices, (255,) * maskzero.shape[2])
  maskedimg = cv2.bitwise_and(res, maskzero)

  # smoothed = cv2.medianBlur(maskedimg,3)
  gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(maskedimg, (3, 3), 0)

  fgmask = fgbg.apply(gaussian)
  cv2.imshow("backSub",fgmask)

  if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
     break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Did you try using a physical polarization filter in the camera?